# Copy files from one folder to other (and not overwrite)

Tags: python, os.walk

I am using the following code to copy files from one folder to other, but files are getting overwritten, is there anyway to copy files to a new sub folder for each iteration ?

```
for patients in parent:
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(patients):
            for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.dcm'):
                matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))

                s=os.path.join(root, filename)
                d =os.path.join(dst, filename)
                shutil.copy(s, d)
```

Comment: you can't have in folder two files with the same name - you have to check if this name exists in folder and then use different name for new or old file.

Comment: Yea I see that, but I am looking for a solution to copy files to a new subdirectory in destination folder after each iteration, instead of changing the names.

Comment: as I said you have to check if filename exist in destination folder and eventually copy with different name. Standard modules doesn't have function to check and rename it automatically and you will have to write own function for this - or use google to check if someone already create something like this.

Comment: BTW: the easiest should be to add to name date with time and milliseconds - like `2020.01.15-15.21.06.1579098166`. With milliseconds it should always create unique names and it should still keep order when you sort names. `datetime.now().strftime('%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S.%s')`

Answer (score 3):

You could simply add a check before your copy:

```py
if not os.path.exists(d):
   shutil.copy(s, d)
```

Comment: thanks, but I want to keep all files, the problem is that their names are same (basically numbered)

Comment: @Stefann as I know standard modules doesn't have function to change number in name automatically and you will have to rename it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use shutil which gives huge amount of choices in order to file operations. Check the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html)

**Code**:

```
import os
import shutil
spath='C:/Path/to/Source'
sfiles = os.listdir(spath)
dpath = 'C:/Path/to/Destination'
for file in sfiles:
if file.endswith('.dcm'):
   shutil.copy(os.path.join(spath,file), os.path.join(dpath,file))
```

If you have questions and if it doesn't work, please comment below. I have tested it and it works in my system.

Comment: The problem is I am copying files from multiple subfolders to single folder, the files are  named as numbers so they get replaced at destination folder, I am looking for a way to copy files in each iteration to a newly created subdirectory (created each time). Thanks for your input though